# PHP Register not sending data to MySQL PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've tested this registration form on my localhost and my VPS. I cannot get it to send data to MySQL at all. The register class does acknowledge errors in the form and it says an account was created successfully, but it never inserts it into the database.

```
<?php
class Register {
private $dbObj = null;
private $dbConf = array('host' => 'localhost', 'user' => 'root', 'pass' => '', 'db' => 'sweater');
private $userArr = Array();
private $referred = false;
public function __construct($params){
    try {
        $this->dbObj = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $this->dbConf['host'] . ';dbname=' . $this->dbConf['db'], $this->dbConf['user'], $this->dbConf['pass']);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        $this->__return($e->getMessage());
    }

    $this->userArr['username']        = trim($params['playerName']);
    $this->userArr['email']           = trim($params['playerEmail']);
    $this->userArr['password']        = trim($params['playerPass']);
    $this->userArr['passwordConfirm'] = trim($params['playerPassConfirm']);
    $this->userArr['color']           = trim($params['playerColor']);
    if($this->ipExists($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])){
        $this->__return('You\'re not allowed to register more than 4 accounts per IP on our server!');
    }
    if($this->verifyInput($this->userArr)) {
        if($this->insertUser($this->userArr)){
            echo $this->__return('Your account has been created successfully.', false);
        } else {
            $this->__return('unable to create account? error code 9998');
        }
    }
}

private function verifyInput($userArr){
    foreach($userArr as $key => $val){
        switch($key){
            case 'username':
                if($val == '')
                    $this->__return('You are required to enter a username.');
                if($this->userExists($val))
                    $this->__return("Another player already has that username!");
                if(strlen($val) < 4)
                    $this->__return('Your uername must be at least 4 characters in length!');
                if(strlen($val) > 12)
                    $this->__return('Your username must be less than 12 characters in length!');
                if(!ctype_alnum($val))
                    $this->__return('Your username can only contain letters & numbers.');
                break;
            case 'email':
                if($val == '')
                    $this->__return('You are required to enter an email address.');
                if(!filter_var($val, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
                    $this->__return('You have entered an invalid email address.');
                if($this->emailExists($val))
                    $this->__return('A user has already registered with that email address.');
                break;
            case 'password':
                if($val == '')
                    $this->__return('You are required to enter a password.');
                if(strlen($val) < 4)
                    $this->__return('Your password must be at least 4 characters in length!');
                if(strlen($val) > 40)
                    $this->__return('Your password must be less than 40 characters in length!');
                if($val !== $userArr['passwordConfirm'])
                    $this->__return('The passwords you entered do not match.');
                break;
            case 'passwordConfirm':
                if($val == '')
                    $this->__return('You are required to confirm your password for verification purposes.');
                if($val !== $userArr['password'])
                    $this->__return('The passwords you entered do not match.');
                break;
            case 'color':
                if(!is_numeric($val)){
                    $this->__return('Color is not numeric');
                }
                if($val > 14){
                    $this->__return('Invalid color ID');
                }
                break;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

private function insertUser($userArr) {
    try {
        $strQuery = "INSERT INTO users (ID, Username, Password, Email, RegisteredTime, RegisteredIP, LoginKey, LoginToken, Active, Status, Coins, Credits, Badges, Color) VALUES (null, :Username, :Password, :Email, :RegTime, :RegIP, null, null, :Active, 0, 10000, :Credits, '[]', :Color)";
        $objStatement = $this->dbObj->prepare($strQuery);
        $objStatement->bindValue(':Username', $userArr['username']);
        $objStatement->bindValue(':Password', md5($userArr['password']));
        $objStatement->bindValue(':Email', $userArr['email']);
        $objStatement->bindValue(':RegTime', time());
        $objStatement->bindValue(':RegIP', $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
        $objStatement->bindValue(':Color',$userArr['color']);
        $objStatement->execute();
        $objStatement->closeCursor();
        if($objStatement) return true;
        else return false;
    } catch(PDOException $e){
        $this->__return($e->getMessage());
    }

}

private function getPlayerCredits($user) {
    try {
        $strQuery = "SELECT Credits from `users` WHERE Username = :Username";
        $objStatement = $this->dbObj->prepare($strQuery);
        $objStatement->bindValue(':Username', $user);
        $objStatement->execute();
        $objStatement->bindColumn('Credits', $credits);
        $objStatement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOUND);
        $objStatement->closeCursor();
        if($objStatement) return $credits;
        else return false;
    } catch(PDOException $e){
        $this->__return($e->getMessage());
    }

}

private function userExists($username){
    try {
        $strQuery = "SELECT ID FROM `users` WHERE Username = :Username";
        $objStatement = $this->dbObj->prepare($strQuery);
        $objStatement->bindValue(':Username', $username);
        $objStatement->execute();
        $intRows = $objStatement->rowCount();
        $objStatement->closeCursor();
        return $intRows > 0;
    } catch(PDOException $e){
        $this->__return($e->getMessage());
    }
}

private function emailExists($email){
    try {
        $strQuery = "SELECT ID FROM `users` WHERE Email = :Email";
        $objStatement = $this->dbObj->prepare($strQuery);
        $objStatement->bindValue(':Email', $email);
        $objStatement->execute();
        $intRows = $objStatement->rowCount();
        $objStatement->closeCursor();
        return $intRows > 0;
    } catch(PDOException $e){
        $this->__return($e->getMessage());
    }
}

private function ipExists($ip){
    try {
        $strQuery = "SELECT ID FROM `users` WHERE RegisteredIP = :RegIP";
        $objStatement = $this->dbObj->prepare($strQuery);
        $objStatement->bindValue(':RegIP', $ip);
        $objStatement->execute();
        $intRows = $objStatement->rowCount();
        $objStatement->closeCursor();
        return $intRows >= 4;
    } catch(PDOException $e){
        $this->__return($e->getMessage());
    }
}

private function validateReferral($username){
    try {
        $strQuery = "SELECT ID FROM `users` WHERE Username = :Usrn";
        $objStatement = $this->dbObj->prepare($strQuery);
        $objStatement->bindValue(':Usrn', $username);
        $objStatement->execute();
        $intRows = $objStatement->rowCount();
        $objStatement->closeCursor();
        return $intRows > 0;
    } catch(PDOException $e){
        $this->__return($e->getMessage());
    }
}

private function __return($msg, $error = true){
    $returnArr = Array('error' => $error, 'message' => $msg);
    if($error){
        echo json_encode($returnArr);
        die();
    } else{
        return json_encode($returnArr);
    }
}
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" href="//www.<?php echo $config['WEB_HOST']; ?>/favicon.ico">
    <title>Polar - The #1 CPPS</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.polarcp.com/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.polarcp.com/assets/css/style.main.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" id="page-nav">
            <div class="container">
           <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="//www.<?php echo $config['WEB_HOST']; ?>/logo.png" width="100" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="https://polarcp.com">Home</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Register</a></li>
      </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header register"><div class="overlay">
                Create an Account
                </div></div>
                <div style="padding-top:100px"></div>
                <div align="center">
                    <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
                    <!-- Register -->
                    <ins class="adsbygoogle"
                         style="display:inline-block;width:728px;height:90px"
                         data-ad-client="ca-pub-6294131573779014"
                         data-ad-slot="2822232685"></ins>
                    <script>
                    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
                    </script>
                </div>
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2" id="top-pad" style="padding-top:30px">

                <p>You're on your way to joining the <b>#1 CPPS</b>! All you need to do is take a minute or two to fill out the registration form below. Once completed you will be able to join your fellow penguins in the game!</p>
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                <form id="reg-form">
                <div class="alert alert-danger" id="register-alert" style="display:none">There was an error</div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="playerName" placeholder="Username">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="playerEmail" placeholder="Email">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="playerPass" placeholder="Password">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="playerPassConfirm" placeholder="Repeat your password">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <span style="font-size:14px;color:#666;">
                    If you were referred to Polar by an existing player, enter their name here and you will both receive a reward. This is completely optional!</span><br/><br />
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="playerReferral" placeholder="Player who referred you" <?php if(isset($_GET['ref'])){ echo 'value="' . $_GET['ref'] . '" '; } ?>>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LfhYiITAAAAAJiwF0Meg8v_SZuDXxvw10ImUuAz"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Create</button>
                  </div>
                </form>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4" id="penguin-preview">
                    <img id="penguin-color" src="https://cdn.polarcp.com/assets/images/colors/1.png" width="180" />
                    <br />
                    <div id="color-picker">
                    <div class="color darkblue selected"></div>
                    <div class="color green"></div>
                    <div class="color hotpink"></div>
                    <div class="color black"></div>
                    <div class="color red"></div>
                    <div class="color orange"></div>
                    <div class="color yellow"></div><br/>
                    <div class="color purple"></div>
                    <div class="color brown"></div>
                    <div class="color pink"></div>
                    <div class="color darkgreen"></div>
                    <div class="color blue"></div>
                    <div class="color limegreen"></div>
                    <div class="color gray"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.polarcp.com/assets/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $('.color').click(function(e) {
            var color = $(e.target).attr('class').split(' ')[1];
            colorPicker.select(color);
        });
    });

    var colorPicker = {
        selectedColor: 'darkblue',
        colors: {'darkblue': 1, 'green': 2, 'hotpink': 3, 'black': 4, 'red': 5, 'orange': 6, 'yellow': 7, 'purple': 8, 'brown': 9, 'pink': 10, 'darkgreen': 11, 'blue': 12, 'limegreen': 13, 'gray': 14},
        select: function(color) {
            if($('.'+this.selectedColor).hasClass('selected')) {
                $('.'+this.selectedColor).attr('class', 'color '+this.selectedColor);
            }
            this.selectedColor = color;
            $('.'+color).addClass('selected');
            $('#penguin-color').attr('src', 'https://cdn.polarcp.com/assets/images/colors/'+this.colors[this.selectedColor]+'.png');
        }
    }

    $('#reg-form').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var formData = {
            'playerName': $('#playerName').val(),
            'playerEmail': $('#playerEmail').val(),
            'playerPass': $('#playerPass').val(),
            'playerPassConfirm': $('#playerPassConfirm').val(),
            'playerColor': colorPicker.colors[colorPicker.selectedColor],
            'playerReferral': $('#playerReferral').val(),
            'g-recaptcha-response': $('#g-recaptcha-response').val()
        };
        $.post('lib/create_account.php', formData, function(recv){
            if(recv.error){
                $('#register-alert').html('<strong>An error occured:</strong> ' + recv.message);
            } else {
                $('#register-alert').attr('class', 'alert alert-success');
                $('#register-alert').html('<strong>Success!</strong> Your account has been created.');
            }
            $('#register-alert').fadeIn(200);
        }, 'json');
    })
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'll take a look for you, it might take a little though, you have a lot of code.
I just thought I'd let u know so u don't lose hope :P

Comment: PS: is there any specific function in your class that's going wrong, or is it just a general error (ie; none of it works). Also, what are your field (column) names so I can try to replicate your DB on my system? Thanks :)

Comment: It just doesn't work at all. It'll say the account was created successfully but it'll never insert the user into the database. ID, Username, Password, Email, RegisteredTime, RegisteredIP, LoginKey, LoginToken, Active, Status, Coins, Credits, Badges, Color

Comment: OK, thanks :)
I'll have a look now

Comment: Thanks I appreciate it.

Comment: You have `try/catch` blocks for `PDOException`, but you never set `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`. See http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

Comment: Where is `$params` has been defined?

Answer (score 1):

Quite a simple fix!

On line 103, you were trying to execute a statement without binding all of the values (you forgot to bind values to ':Credits' and ':Active'), so I've added 2 new lines on lines 100 and 101 to do that for you. To get those lines to work, i had to add extra elements ('credits' and 'active') to `$userArr`, which is done on lines 21 and 22.

Here is the fixed and tested code, enjoy ;)

```
<?php
class Register {
  private $dbObj = null;
  private $dbConf = array('host' => 'localhost', 'user' => 'root', 'pass' => '', 'db' => 'sweater');
  private $userArr = Array();
  private $referred = false;
  public function __construct($params){
      try {
          $this->dbObj = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $this->dbConf['host'] . ';dbname=' . $this->dbConf['db'], $this->dbConf['user'], $this->dbConf['pass']);
      } catch(PDOException $e) {
          $this->__return($e->getMessage());
      }

      $this->userArr['username']        = trim($params['playerName']);
      $this->userArr['email']           = trim($params['playerEmail']);
      $this->userArr['password']        = trim($params['playerPass']);
      $this->userArr['passwordConfirm'] = trim($params['playerPassConfirm']);
      $this->userArr['color']           = trim($params['playerColor']);

      //NEW VALUES
      $this->userArr['credits'] = 0;
      $this->userArr['active'] = 0;

      if($this->ipExists($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])){
          $this->__return('You\'re not allowed to register more than 4 accounts per IP on our server!');
      }
      if($this->verifyInput($this->userArr)) {
          if($this->insertUser($this->userArr)){
              echo $this->__return('Your account has been created successfully.', false);
          } else {
              $this->__return('unable to create account? error code 9998');
          }
      }
  }

  private function verifyInput($userArr){
      foreach($userArr as $key => $val){
          switch($key){
              case 'username':
                  if($val == '')
                      $this->__return('You are required to enter a username.');
                  if($this->userExists($val))
                      $this->__return("Another player already has that username!");
                  if(strlen($val) < 4)
                      $this->__return('Your uername must be at least 4 characters in length!');
                  if(strlen($val) > 12)
                      $this->__return('Your username must be less than 12 characters in length!');
                  if(!ctype_alnum($val))
                      $this->__return('Your username can only contain letters & numbers.');
                  break;
              case 'email':
                  if($val == '')
                      $this->__return('You are required to enter an email address.');
                  if(!filter_var($val, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
                      $this->__return('You have entered an invalid email address.');
                  if($this->emailExists($val))
                      $this->__return('A user has already registered with that email address.');
                  break;
              case 'password':
                  if($val == '')
                      $this->__return('You are required to enter a password.');
                  if(strlen($val) < 4)
                      $this->__return('Your password must be at least 4 characters in length!');
                  if(strlen($val) > 40)
                      $this->__return('Your password must be less than 40 characters in length!');
                  if($val !== $userArr['passwordConfirm'])
                      $this->__return('The passwords you entered do not match.');
                  break;
              case 'passwordConfirm':
                  if($val == '')
                      $this->__return('You are required to confirm your password for verification purposes.');
                  if($val !== $userArr['password'])
                      $this->__return('The passwords you entered do not match.');
                  break;
              case 'color':
                  if(!is_numeric($val)){
                      $this->__return('Color is not numeric');
                  }
                  if($val > 14){
                      $this->__return('Invalid color ID');
                  }
                  break;
          }
      }
      return true;
  }

  private function insertUser($userArr) {
      try {
          $strQuery = "INSERT INTO users (ID, Username, Password, Email, RegisteredTime, RegisteredIP, LoginKey, LoginToken, Active, Status, Coins, Credits, Badges, Color) VALUES (null, :Username, :Password, :Email, :RegTime, :RegIP, null, null, :Active, 0, 10000, :Credits, '[]', :Color)";
          $objStatement = $this->dbObj->prepare($strQuery);
          $objStatement->bindValue(':Username', $userArr['username']);
          $objStatement->bindValue(':Password', md5($userArr['password']));
          $objStatement->bindValue(':Email', $userArr['email']);
          $objStatement->bindValue(':RegTime', time());
          $objStatement->bindValue(':RegIP', $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
          $objStatement->bindValue(':Color',$userArr['color']);

          //NEW VALUES
          $objStatement->bindValue(':Credits', $userArr['credits']);
          $objStatement->bindValue(':Active', $userArr['active']);

          $objStatement->execute();
          $objStatement->closeCursor();
          if($objStatement) return true;
          else return false;
      } catch(PDOException $e){
          $this->__return($e->getMessage());
      }

  }

  private function getPlayerCredits($user) {
      try {
          $strQuery = "SELECT Credits from `users` WHERE Username = :Username";
          $objStatement = $this->dbObj->prepare($strQuery);
          $objStatement->bindValue(':Username', $user);
          $objStatement->execute();
          $objStatement->bindColumn('Credits', $credits);
          $objStatement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOUND);
          $objStatement->closeCursor();
          if($objStatement) return $credits;
          else return false;
      } catch(PDOException $e){
          $this->__return($e->getMessage());
      }

  }

  private function userExists($username){
      try {
          $strQuery = "SELECT ID FROM `users` WHERE Username = :Username";
          $objStatement = $this->dbObj->prepare($strQuery);
          $objStatement->bindValue(':Username', $username);
          $objStatement->execute();
          $intRows = $objStatement->rowCount();
          $objStatement->closeCursor();
          return $intRows > 0;
      } catch(PDOException $e){
          $this->__return($e->getMessage());
      }
  }

  private function emailExists($email){
      try {
          $strQuery = "SELECT ID FROM `users` WHERE Email = :Email";
          $objStatement = $this->dbObj->prepare($strQuery);
          $objStatement->bindValue(':Email', $email);
          $objStatement->execute();
          $intRows = $objStatement->rowCount();
          $objStatement->closeCursor();
          return $intRows > 0;
      } catch(PDOException $e){
          $this->__return($e->getMessage());
      }
  }

  private function ipExists($ip){
      try {
          $strQuery = "SELECT ID FROM `users` WHERE RegisteredIP = :RegIP";
          $objStatement = $this->dbObj->prepare($strQuery);
          $objStatement->bindValue(':RegIP', $ip);
          $objStatement->execute();
          $intRows = $objStatement->rowCount();
          $objStatement->closeCursor();
          return $intRows >= 4;
      } catch(PDOException $e){
          $this->__return($e->getMessage());
      }
  }

  private function validateReferral($username){
      try {
          $strQuery = "SELECT ID FROM `users` WHERE Username = :Usrn";
          $objStatement = $this->dbObj->prepare($strQuery);
          $objStatement->bindValue(':Usrn', $username);
          $objStatement->execute();
          $intRows = $objStatement->rowCount();
          $objStatement->closeCursor();
          return $intRows > 0;
      } catch(PDOException $e){
          $this->__return($e->getMessage());
      }
  }

  private function __return($msg, $error = true){
      $returnArr = Array('error' => $error, 'message' => $msg);
      if($error){
          echo json_encode($returnArr);
          die();
      } else{
          return json_encode($returnArr);
      }
  }
}

//This is just a little extra bit that I added for testing, feel free to use it! :D
$params = array(
  'playerName' => "dibdibs",
  'playerEmail' => "dibdibs@g.com",
  'playerPass' => "passwd123",
  'playerPassConfirm' => "passwd123",
  'playerColor' => "1"
);
$u = new Register($params);
?>
```

I'll keep the code on my computer, just let me know if you need any more help :)

PS: You're using MD5 for hashing your passwords, you should really be using something like PBKDF2, but if you want something simple, SHA-512 is OK too. Do something like this...

```
$hashedPass = "";

for($i=0; $i<1024; $i++){ //It's good to iterate password hashes many times.
  $hashedPass = hash("sha512", $userArr['password']);
}

$objStatement->bindValue(':Password', $hashedPass);
```

Comment: Still can't seem to get it to work. Perhaps the issue is with my form itself?

Comment: What does your form look like, post the HTML in your question and I'll take a look at it for you :)

Sorry for the late reply, I think we're in different timezones.

Comment: I've added the HTML. It's directly below my PHP but begins with <!DOCTYPE html> so it'd be relatively easy to point out. Thanks for all of your help I really appreciate it.

Comment: it looks like an AJAX problem, change this line `$.post('lib/create_account.php', formData, function(recv){` (_somewhere around line 335_), to this `$.post('./lib/create_account.php', formData, function(recv){`, and let me know what happens. I can't really test AJAX stuff properly on my server.